# (Why) Can't MySQL use index in such cases?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

1 - `PRIMARY` used in a secondary index, e.g. secondary index on (`PRIMARY`,`column1`)

2 - I'm aware mysql cannot continue using the rest of an index as soon as one part was used for a range scan, however: `IN (...,...,...)` is not considered a range, is it? Yes, it is a range, but I've read on mysqlperformanceblog.com that `IN` behaves differently than `BETWEEN` according to the use of index.

Could anyone confirm those two points? Or tell me why this is not possible? Or how it could be possible?

UPDATE:

Links:
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/10/using-union-to-implement-loose-index-scan-to-mysql/
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/14/mysql-followup-on-union-for-query-optimization-query-profiling/comment-page-1/#comment-952521

UPDATE 2: example of nested SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM user_d1 uo 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM `user_d1` ui
    WHERE ui.birthdate BETWEEN '1990-05-04' AND '1991-05-04'
    AND ui.id=uo.id
)    
ORDER BY uo.timestamp_lastonline DESC
LIMIT 20
```

So, the outer `SELECT` uses `timestamp_lastonline` for sorting, the inner either `PK` to connect with the outer or `birthdate` for filtering.

What other options rather than this query are there if MySQL cannot use index on a range scan and for sorting?

Comment: Can you provide links where it says that `IN` is considered a range or at least clarify what problems you've stumbled into exactly, talking without actual queries and `EXPLAIN` output is difficult.

Comment: @N.B.: thx, I've added the Links to mysqlperformanceblog. The actual problem is I am trying to find a solution for e.g. `SELECT * FROM user WHERE birthdate IN/BETWEEN ORDER BY last_online LIMIT 20`. However after already 2 weeks now and dozens of tries I still haven't. The links deal exactly with this problem, that mysql can't use index on range and for `ORDER BY`... though you rather store the birthdate than age of the user in db, not even `WHERE age IN(...)` works for me using the index...

Comment: Why would you want 1. anyway? As the primary is unique afaik, adding a second column doesn't actually do anything, as the first part is unique in itself. if you have the primary key you'll use that, if you don't, then that secondairy index will not help you?

Comment: @Chris - as Nanne pointed out, the secondary index in the way you've set it up does nothing. Indexing `birthdate` without making it compound should be enough. However, what performance issue are you exactly solving here? What is the output of your `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: @Nane: because PK could be used to `JOIN` another table, whereas the second column would help filtering...

Comment: @N.B.: well, my comment was meant for point 2, as you answered that. However, it is related to point 1: having 2 indexes, one on `last_online` for fast sorting and one on `birthdate`for fast filtering, which mysql cannot use together. So, having a nested `SELECT`, meaning the inner is for filtering and the outer for sorting is much faster already... however, and index on PK and `birthdate` would help filter and connect those queries. (I've put and example into the post).

Comment: Have you read xaprb's article on late row lookups perhaps? It seems it's what you're looking for.

Comment: @N.B.: do you have a link to it maybe? thank you very much!

Comment: [Here it is](http://explainextended.com/2011/02/11/late-row-lookups-innodb/)

Comment: @N.B.: yes, thank you, I've read that. But that's not the problem, because there is no `WHERE` clause in those queries! So, as soon as there is a `WHERE` clause with a range, the index cannot be used for `ORDER BY`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column(s) of the primary key can certainly be used in a secondary index, but it's not often worthwhile.  The primary key guarantees uniqueness, so any columns listed after it cannot be used for range lookups.  The only time it will help is when a query can use the index alone

As for your nested select, the extra complication should not beat the simplest query:

```
SELECT * FROM user_d1 uo 
WHERE uo.birthdate BETWEEN '1990-05-04' AND '1991-05-04'
ORDER BY uo.timestamp_lastonline DESC
LIMIT 20
```

MySQL will choose between a `birthdate` index or a `timestamp_lastonline` index based on which it feels will have the best chance of scanning fewer rows.  In either case, the column should be the first one in the index.  The `birthdate` index will also carry a sorting penalty, but might be worthwhile if a large number of recent users will have birth dates outside of that range.

If you wish to control the order, or potentially improve performance, a `(timestamp_lastonline, birthdate)` or `(birthdate, timestamp_lastonline)` index might help.  If it doesn't, and you really need to select based on the birthdate first, then you should select from the inner query instead of filtering on it:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM user_d1 ui
    WHERE ui.birthdate BETWEEN '1990-05-04' AND '1991-05-04'
) as uo
ORDER BY uo.timestamp_lastonline DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Even then, MySQL's optimizer might choose to rewrite your query if it finds a `timestamp_lastonline` index but no `birthdate` index.

And yes, `IN (..., ..., ...)` behaves differently than `BETWEEN`.  Only the latter can effectively use a range scan over an index; the former would look up each item individually.

Comment: thank you eswald, you really provided a lot of new insights for me! your post really helped me a lot, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

2.`IN` will obviously differ from `BETWEEN`. If you have an index on that column, `BETWEEN` will need to get the starting point and it's all done. If you have `IN`, it will look for a matching value in the index value by value thus it will look for the values as many times as there are values compared to `BETWEEN`'s one time look.

Answer (score 0):

1. yes @Andrius_Naruševičius is right the *IN* statement is merely shorthand for *EQUALS OR EQUALS OR EQUALS* has no inherent order whatsoever where as BETWEEN is a comparison operator with an implicit greater than or less than and therefore absolutely loves indexes
2. I honestly have no idea what you are talking about, but it does seem you are asking a good question I just have no notion what it is :-). Are you saying that a primary key cannot contain a second index? because it absolutely can. The primary key never needs to be indexed because it is ALWAYS indexed automatically, so if you are getting an error/warn (I assume you are?) about supplementary indices then it's not the second, third index causing it it's the PRIMARY KEY not needing it, and you mentioning that probably is the error. Having said that I have no idea what question you asked - it's my answer to my best guess as to your actual question.

Comment: conners, thank you for your answer! 1 (your 2nd): no, the question is why mysql cannot use PK as part of a secondary index. If you ask why I need it: for nested `SELECT`s, `JOIN`s etc that would use PK to `JOIN ON`. 2 (your 1st): my problem is: mysql can use index for ranges, but if e.g. index on (birthdate, gender) and you want birthdate between ... and ... and gender=1, then mysql can use the index only for birthdate, but not gender, index (gender, birthdate) will work. SO: range must be last, as well as for `ORDER BY`! SO: what if multiple ranges? What if range AND index for `ORDER BY`??

Comment: ahh I see - you are firmly into the realms of DBA type digestion of subtle issues which literally are the raison d'etre for ORACLE and Microsoft to sell their products. The "Optimised Engine" that MySQL employs is employing choices... if you want to read about those choices... http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Top10SQLPerformanceTips

Comment: you can even tailor your mysql engine to make it do these things "better" http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_Custom_Engine